# Can we create and execute rpc calls within two process that is running in the same system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpc

RPC calls are used for IPC to share data among processes. It provides a bidirectional communication link between the processes.  There are IPC mechanisms to share data local to the system using pipes and message queues which are unidirectional.Can we use the RPC to share the data among processes that are running on the same system instead of the process that are running on two different systems.

Comment: Send the data over RPC, what's the problem so far? Of course, it won't be synchronous.

Comment: Why would it make any difference whether the RPC endpoints are on the same or different systems? The network protocol hides this from the application.

Comment: This sounds like an exam question, not an actual programming problem you're having. Have you actually tried programming it? If you can't get it to work, please post your code.

Comment: And what does this have to do with the Linux kernel? RPC doesn't operate in the kernel, it's an at a much higher layer.

Comment: @Barmar: I was reading through some design docs on making a bidirection messaging. Hence thought that RPC would be a good choice.